# An INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

any help for this please ?
I want to return all those who live in france, then compare them with those who live in BELguim if they have the same name or name_done show the result

```
declare
  cursor c is select namer from poeple where city = 'France';
  c_res c%rowtype;
begin
  open c;
  loop
    fetch c into c_res;
    exit when c%notfound;
    select * from poeple tw where city = 'BELguim' AND (c_res.namer = tw.namer OR c_res.namer = tw.namer || ' _done' );
  end loop;
  close c;
end;
```

Comment: Are you sure the cursor `c` really has to have the `'France' '` condition? Shouldn't it be rather `'France'` ? It occurs to me that there is one `'` and one space more than there should be.

Comment: @nop77svk yes edit done

Answer (score 1):

Why use a cursor?  You can write this with a single query:

```
select pb.*
from poeple pf join
     poeple pb
     on pf.city = 'France' and pb.city = 'BELgium' and
        (pf.namer = pb.namer or pf.namer = pb.namer || ' _done');
```

The issue with your code is that PL/SQL does not allow queries to return anything from code blocks.  You can print out the results, insert values into variables, or put them in another table. But, you cannot just have the results from the query.

Comment: well actually because further I'll have to update each row rendred so I need cursors and I can't user join with update

Comment: Then you should use an `update` statement, not a `select`.  You might be able to do what you want with an `update` and no cursors.  You can certainly do what you need using `merge`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with :

> select * from poeple tw where   city='BELguim' AND (c_res.namer
>   =tw.namer OR c_res.namer     =tw.namer || ' _done' );

You cannot write the `SQL` directly in `PL/SQL`. The PL/SQL engine expects an `INTO` clause.

Looking at your code, you don't need the `cursor c`. it could be written in a single SQL. Which brings it back to Gordon's query :

```
select pb.*
from poeple pf join
     poeple pb
     on pf.city = 'France' and pb.city = 'BELgium' and
        (pf.namer = pb.namer or pf.namer = pb.namer || ' _done');
```

If you really need PL/SQL for some stuff which you have not explained, for example return the result set as REF CURSOR, then have an `OUT` parameter as `REF CURSOR`. But, you need to explain the requirement.

**If you can do something in SQL, then don't use PL/SQL.**

**EDIT** If your final goal is to update, then use the above query as `USING` clause in the `MERGE` statement.

Comment: yes I need to return the result set so further more I can update each row

Comment: `MERGE` is what you need.